# Stuck with matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve a matrix equation problem and I can't work out the correct form for the equation for it to be valid.

The matrices given are:

A= $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 3\\
    4 & 1 & 5\\
    0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$, B= $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1\\
    3 & 6\\
    1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$, C= $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0\\
    5 & 6\\
    0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

The equation goes as follows:
$AX + B = C - X$

I arrange it to: $X= (C - B)*(A+I)^{-1}$ via the following steps:
$$AX + B = C - X$$
$$AX +X = C - B$$
$$X(A+I) = C - B /(A+I)^{-1}$$
$$X = (C - B) (A+I)^{-1}$$

But the problem is that the matrices $(C-B)$ and $(A+I)^{-1}$ can't be multiplied because they're not chained (the number of rows and collumns don't allow multiplication). I've been looking at this for over half an  hour and can't figure out a different approach. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pre multiply by $(A+I)^{-1}$. Your equation is $(A+I)X=C-B \implies X=(A+I)^{-1}(C-B )$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got to $(A+I)X=(C−B)$

Comment: See we have to be careful with matrix multplication. we have $AX+X$ so number of columns of $A$ must be equal  to number of rows of $X$.

Comment: Can you guide me step to step through how you got from $AX+B=C−X$ to $(A+I)X=(C−B)$? That's the only thing I don't understand. I can find the inverse of $A+I$ just fine.

Comment: $AX+B=C−X $. Adding addtitive inverses of $B$ and $-X$ on both sides we get $AX+(B-B)+X=C+(−X+X)-B\implies AX+I\cdot X=C-B\implies (A+I)X=C-B$. Assuming $(A+I)$ is invertible we premultiply both sides by $(A+I)^{-1}$ i.e. $(A+I)^{-1}(A+I)X=(A+I)^{-1}(C-B)\implies X=(A+I)^{-1}(C-B)$

Comment: I see. Instead of extracting $X$, you extracted $A+I$. Interesting, and also obvious in hindsight. I shall certainly keep this in mind for the future. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X=(A+I)^{-1}(C-B )=\begin{bmatrix}\frac14 &\frac18 &\frac{-11}{8}\\\frac{-1}{2} &\frac14 &\frac14\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 &1\\2 &0\\-1 &1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac98 &\frac{-9}{8}\\\frac54 &\frac{-1}{4}\\-1 &1\end{bmatrix}$

We get two independent solutions for $X$.